# How to log all addresses executed while debugging with GDB?

Tags: gdb

Is it possible to log all executed addresses of a program while debugging it with GDB. So, what I try to achieve is to generate a list of addresses after the program executed successfully. I want to be able distinguish called addresses and not called addresses. An example of such a list would be (of course in practice a lot bigger):

```
0x80483e4
0x80483e6
0x80483e8
0x80483ea
0x80483ec
0x80483ef
0x80483e4
```

I have not found a way to do this. Maybe you know a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do that?

An exceedingly inefficient way to achive such trace in gdb:

```
while 1
 stepi
 x/i $pc
end
```

For analyzing coverage (parts of your program which are executed), try `man gcov` instead.

Comment: Your answer is indeed inefficient, but it kinda works. Some post-processing is needed because of overhead generated by GDB. I won't be able to use gcov, because I only have run-time access via GDB.